# How to retrieve result of COUNT(*) statement through PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How would I retrieve the result of the following COUNT(*) MYSQL statement using PHP?

**MYSQL**

```
$sql= mysql_query ("
                    select count(*)
                    from orders o
                    WHERE order_status IN
                    ('Printed Order', 'Charged Order', 'Exchanged Order', 'Refunded Order', 'Cancelled Order')
                    GROUP BY FIELD
                    (order_status,'Printed Order', 'Charged Order', 'Exchanged Order', 'Refunded Order', 'Cancelled Order')
                  ");
```

**Result of the above query**

```
count(*)
226
19130
593
2603
2892
```

I've tried the following code to retrieve each row in sequence -

**PHP**

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
echo $row[0];
echo $row[1];
echo $row[2];
echo $row[3];
echo $row[4];
```

Which produces the following error : `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 ...`

I know I'm missing something really simple, but would somebody please show me the correct way to call the result of the COUNT(*) query.

Comment: Your query returns *5 rows*, you're only fetching the first one.

Comment: Iterate over the rows, not the columns since there is only one

Comment: @juergend - Could you show a brief example of how to iterate through the rows? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query returns 5 rows. You have to loop over them and display the column:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)){
    echo $row[0];
}
```

See also the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

It also make sense using an alias for the count.

```
$sql= mysql_query = "
                    select count(*) as countValue
                    from orders o
                    WHERE order_status IN
                    ('Printed Order', 'Charged Order', 'Exchanged Order', 'Refunded Order', 'Cancelled Order')
                    GROUP BY FIELD
                    (order_status,'Printed Order', 'Charged Order', 'Exchanged Order', 'Refunded Order', 'Cancelled Order')
                  ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)){
    echo $row["countValue"];
}
```

**Warning:** The mysql_ extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add loop to get all the data and use mysqli instead of mysql.

something like this

```
 $sql= "select count(*) as total from orders o WHERE order_status IN
       ('Printed Order', 'Charged Order', 'Exchanged Order', 'Refunded Order', 'Cancelled Order') GROUP BY FIELD (order_status,'Printed Order', 'Charged Order', 'Exchanged Order', 'Refunded Order', 'Cancelled Order')"

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['total'];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

you can also use the same approach with mysql instead of mysqli but mysqli would be better for future use.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql)){
   echo $row['total'];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= mysql_query ("
                    select count(*) as nbre
                    from orders o
                    WHERE order_status IN
                    ('Printed Order', 'Charged Order', 'Exchanged Order', 'Refunded Order', 'Cancelled Order')
                    GROUP BY FIELD
                    (order_status,'Printed Order', 'Charged Order', 'Exchanged Order', 'Refunded Order', 'Cancelled Order')
                  ");


echo $row[0]['nbre'];
```

Comment: yeah , sorry forget it ... i just want to mention that he should add an alias to count(*)